# NoClassDefFoundError when class is clearly in project

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, twitter4j

I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError when the class that cannot be found is clearly in the project.

The error is actually happening with an AsyncTask:

```
    public class PrefAuth extends AsyncTask<SharedPreferences,Object, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(SharedPreferences... params) {
        return TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isAuthenticated) {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            GlobalAppContext.setTwitterFlag(true);
            Log.i("here", "isAuthenticated is true");
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else {
            Log.i("here", "isAuthenticated is false");
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class); 
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The error points to the line `return TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(params[0]);`.  `TwitterUtils` is a class that references Twitter4j.  I have tried order & export on the classpath, moving Twitter4j up to the top.  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding.  Does anyone have any idea why the class can't be found?  Logcat is below:

```
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.auth.AccessToken
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at com.tforan.blobtag4.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(TwitterUtils.java:17)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at com.tforan.blobtag4.SplashActivity$PrefAuth.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:41)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at com.tforan.blobtag4.SplashActivity$PrefAuth.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:1)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-25 00:40:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(5078):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Did you add a library project or a jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the Project > Go to Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export > Check "Android Private Libraries"

then clean and build the project, then run project.

Also check other jar files if you have exported in to your project.

Hope it will help you.